# Count the first row data in SSRS / SQL Query

Tags: asp.net, t-sql, reporting-services

In my SSRS report, there is a matrix showing following data... Every single of data in the matrix is dynamic.

```
Departure    Arravial     Bus name        Tour
01:51        02:01        07 ABY 04
02:02        02:12        07 AB 978
02:21        02:31        07 ABY 04
02:32        02:42        07 AB 978
03:01        03:11        07 ABY 04
03:02        03:12        07 AB 978
03:31        03:41        07 ABY 04
03:42        03:52        07 AB 978
04:01        04:11        07 ABY 04
```

What I want to do is count the first row bus name and put it next to it. Can this be achievable with expressions? or how can I come up with such query in SQL? How can I solve this puzzle?

```
Departure    Arravial     Bus name        Tour
01:51        02:01        07 ABY 04       1
02:02        02:12        07 AB 978       
02:21        02:31        07 ABY 04       2
02:32        02:42        07 AB 978       
03:01        03:11        07 ABY 04       3
03:02        03:12        07 AB 978       
03:31        03:41        07 ABY 04       4
03:42        03:52        07 AB 978       
04:01        04:11        07 ABY 04       5
```

This is my query by the way,

```
SELECT HCPD.DepartureTime, HCPD.ArrivalTime, V.BusName
FROM HAT_CALISMA_PLANI HCP WITH(NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN HAT_CALISMA_PLANI_DETAY HCPD WITH(NOLOCK) ON HCPD.HatCalismaPlaniKey = HCP.HatCalismaPlaniKey
INNER JOIN VALIDATOR V WITH(NOLOCK) ON V.ValidatorKey = HCPD.ValidatorKey
WHERE HCPD.DepartureTime = @Time AND HCP.HatKey = @HatKey
ORDER BY HCPD.DepartureTime
```

Edit: Bus names are dynamic.

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to do this by applying a `row_number()` to your query:

```
select DepartureTime, ArrivalTime, BusName,
  case when BusName ='07 ABY 04' 
        then cast(rn as varchar(10))
        else '' end Tour
from
(
  SELECT HCPD.DepartureTime, HCPD.ArrivalTime, V.BusName,
    row_number() over(partition by busname order by departure) rn
  FROM HAT_CALISMA_PLANI HCP WITH(NOLOCK)
  INNER JOIN HAT_CALISMA_PLANI_DETAY HCPD WITH(NOLOCK) 
    ON HCPD.HatCalismaPlaniKey = HCP.HatCalismaPlaniKey
  INNER JOIN VALIDATOR V WITH(NOLOCK) 
    ON V.ValidatorKey = HCPD.ValidatorKey
  WHERE HCPD.DepartureTime = @Time 
    AND HCP.HatKey = @HatKey
) x
order by DepartureTime;
```

Here is a sample query:

```
select departure, arrival, busname,
  case when busname ='07 ABY 04' 
        then cast(rn as varchar(10))
        else '' end Tour
from
(
  select departure, arrival, busname,
    row_number() over(partition by busname order by departure) rn
  from yourtable
) x
order by departure;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/326d0/7)

Comment: I noticed you built up the schema manually, but this could have been done faster by just copying and pasting OP's data into the "Text to DDL" utility on SQL Fiddle.  You probably knew about this feature, but I wanted to mention it because I've recently improved it a bit to better handle various input formats. Here's an example of the output it would produce: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c4682

Comment: @jake wow I actually did not know that. It will significantly reduce my need to type. Thanks for the info. :)